# the difference between 出价 发价 报价 提价

Tags: meaning, difference

Anyone know the the difference between 出价 发价 报价 提价？
I want to know the detailed different meaning about those words.
thank you for answering my question.

Comment: What is your own guess? Please put that under your question too.

Answer (score 2):

出价 - offer a buying price (offer)

报价 - quote a selling price (quotation)

*发价 is a less common term for 报价*

提价 = 提高价格 = raise the price